# How do I install Imagick for PHP without PEAR?

Tags: php, pear, imagick

I've downloaded and installed Imagick and Imagick-devel. I now want to use it with PHP but every guide I've found has the following steps:

```
pecl install imagick
echo "extension=imagick.so" > /etc/php.d/imagick.ini
```

The first step `pecl` is part of PEAR, a package that I don't need and don't want to install. How would I install and hook Imagick to PHP without that pecl command?

OS: CentOS 6

Comment: Depends on what you have on your system at the moment. If you have the `imagick.so` file already, I expect the extension directive would be sufficient. What operating system are you using?

Comment: @halfer Thanks. I'm using CentOS 6 Server.

Answer (score 2):

Either your package manager has a php-imagick package, or you simply have to install pear/pecl to install the php extension.

PEAR is the only php package manager that supports installing php/pecl extensions, so unless your linux distribution provides a package itself, you have to use it.

Alternatively, you can download the tgz, extract it, compile it, install it and activate it manually. You have to know what you're doing in this case, though.

Comment: " You have to know what you're doing in this case, though." that's the part I'm asking about. weekday are the steps and configurations to compile it and install it for php?